# Is this characteristic function zero-free in any strip?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a probability density $p(x) = c \frac{e^{-(x-\alpha)^2/(2 \beta^2)}}{x^2 + \gamma^2}$, with support $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$,
where $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ are real constants (the last two strictly positive) and c the normalization constant.

I'm pretty sure the Fourier Transform $\hat{p}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i z x} p(x) \, dx$ is an entire function of z, somewhat similar to the easy FT of the Gaussian density without the denominator. The latter is zero-free in the complex z-plane.

Is $\hat{p}(z)$ similarly zero-free in the whole $z$-plane or perhaps a strip? If so, how do I prove it?

Comment: What I note is that $p(x)$ is essentially the product of a Gaussian distribution and a Cauchy distribution, both of which have known characteristic functions (CFs). So one should be able to express the CF of their product as the convolution of these CFs; hopefully one can either do that explicitly, or deduce from this form where the zeros could be (via the argument principle, perhaps.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It inspired to me to think some more about a closed-form evaluation of $\hat{p}(z)$. Now I've got a formula, involving some exponentials and cumulative normal functions. Given that, I should be able to construct a proof.